# add subsections in section of UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Searched a lot but all in vain. I have a nested `NSMutableArray` of `NSMutableDictionary`. I want to have sections within section of `UITableView`. Following is my array:

```
    <__NSArrayM 0x7ffe4267efb0>(
{
    "group_title" = "Seller Information";
    "group_values" =     (
                {
            key = "First Name";
            value = test;
        },
                {
            key = "Last Name";
            value = testl;
        }
    );
},
{
    "group_title" = "Buyer Information";
    "group_values" =     (
                {
            key = "First Name";
            value = Demo1;
        },
                {
            key = "Last Name";
            value = Demo;
        }
    );
},
{
    "group_title" = "Transaction Information";
    "group_values" =     (
                {
            key = Status;
            value = Active;
        },
                {
            key = "MLS #";
            value = "15-284";
        },
                {
            key = Address;
            value = "1101 Fargo Ave";
        },
                {
            key = County;
            value = Dickinson;
        },
                {
            key = Zipcode;
            value = 51360;
        },
                {
            key = Contingencies;
            value =             (
                                {
                    key = "General Inspection";
                    value =                     (
                                                {
                            key = "Contingency Verbiage";
                            value = "Inspection Results and balance of this paragraph";
                        }
                    );
                },
                                {
                    key = "New Construction";
                    value =                     (
                                                {
                            key = "Contingency Group";
                            value = "If Required";
                        },
                                                {
                            key = "Days Until Due";
                            value = 5;
                        }
                    );
                }
            );
        }
    );
}
)
```

If you go through the above array, then `group_title` is the number of sections I want. `key`,'value' in `group_values` is the number of rows in each section.

For key `Contingencies`, there is nested data. So I want to display it as follows:

```
Transaction Information // section title
    Contingencies // sub-section title
     General Inspection // sub-sub-section title
       Contingency Verbiage  //value
     New Construction // sub-sub-section title
       Contingency Group  //value
       Days Until Due    //value



  -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [dictData count];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSMutableArray *arr = [[dictData valueForKey:@"group_values"] objectAtIndex:section];
    NSUInteger numberOfRows = arr.count; // For second level section headers
    for (id row  in arr) {
        if([[row objectForKey:@"value"] isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]]) {
            numberOfRows += [[row valueForKey:@"value"]  count];
        }
    }
    return numberOfRows;
}
```

I know that  I have to manipulate the subsections as cells only but not sure about how to do it.

How to access the sub-section in `cellforrowatindexpath`?

Please help. How do I solve and implement this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use delegate method `indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath` to add level of indentation to the cell, so if you want to show the sub-section then simply return an `NSInteger` value say 1, the return value represent the depth of the specified row to show its hierarchical position in the section.

so far example the return value should be

```
  Contingencies // sub-section title - 1
     General Inspection // sub-sub-section title - 2
       Contingency Verbiage  //value - 3
     New Construction // sub-sub-section title - 2
       Contingency Group  //value - 3
       Days Until Due    //value - 3
```

Adding sample code.

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        //Set the indentation width, so that each indentation level width will increase by it.
        cell.indentationWidth = 5;

        //Show the value from corresponding indexPath
 NSArray *arr = [[dictData valueForKey:@"group_values"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
NSMutableArray *items = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:arr];
// For second level section headers
    for (id row  in arr) {
        if([[row objectForKey:@"value"] isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]]) {
            [items addObjectsFromArray:[row valueForKey:@"value"]];
        }
    }
NSDictionary *item = items[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel.text = item[@"key"];

        return cell;

    }
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        //Retrive the right indentation for item at indexPath
 NSArray *arr = [[dictData valueForKey:@"group_values"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
if (indexPath.row < arr.count) {
return 0
}
// For second level section headers
return 1
    }
```

Comment: thanks but what do I write in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` for the sub-sections?

Comment: you don't have to do anything  specific in `cellForRowAtIndexPath ` because `indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath ` will give the indentation to the cell based on sub section defined.

Comment: Can you please show me some sample code for this? I am not sure how to include this in my code. I have given my code in the question.